# React native on double backpress shows white screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

When I press application back button twice faster it shows blank screen.
its not redirecting any where just shows white screen.

```
handleBackPress() {
this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
return true;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

White screen may be because it lead to some other unmounted screen or towards the splash screen where there is nothing to render. That might be your stack management problem